# What exactly is being tested as "not True:" and how?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I copied a section of code from a reading assignment, and I have followed the example code using PyCharm. But I am confused as to what the purpose of the Boolean in **def to_string "if not True"**. Please dumb it down a little, what is being tested as "not True" and how?

I have a few guesses but I end up thinking in circles.

```
# instance helpers -------------------------------------
def to_string(self, optional_title = "-------"):
    if not True:    # placeholder for real test
    ret_str = ( (optional_title
                 + "\n  name: {}"
                 + "\n    id: {}"
                 + "\n  temp: {}(F).").
                format(self.name, self.id, self.temperature) )
    return ret_str
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it says right next to the test in the comment it's a placeholder for a real test. `not True` will always evaluate to `False` so the `if` statment will never be executed with the placeholder.

Comment: isn't it missing `pass` statement?

Comment: @M.Volf I'm just assuming OP messed up the indentation when pasting the code. Since this is not relevant for the question what `if not True:` does I didn't even mention it.

Comment: Got it, thank you. I accidentally forgot to add one line. The code was meant to be done in stages to facilitate writing code. The line that was not added was: optional_title = " ---------- " and it should've been placed under the if statement.